# I am writing unit test in python. I am getting this error while importing my modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, pycharm

```
from src.controller.requestValidator.project import TaskGroupListSchema
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

I have tried the above with different variations but the same error is coming.

like with 0, 1 version in `sys.path.append`
I am trying this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("1, ../src/controller/requestValidator/project")
```

Comment: If you want absolute imports in a multi-module project, you can set the import path when running the program e.g. `PYTHONPATH=. python main.py`. For larger projects I suggest virtualenv or pipenv.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, using the full path.

```py
import sys 

sys.path.append("/my/path/to/src/controller/requestValidator/project")
```